# Object is appearing black after converting from USDZ file to SceneKit(SCN) file format

Tags: ios, scenekit, arkit, usdz

Right now i am exploring Apple provided USDZ file ([Toy Drummer](https://developer.apple.com/augmented-reality/quick-look/models/drummertoy/toy_drummer.usdz)) in a sample ARKit based project.

So to do that first i have imported corresponding USDZ file to my art.scnassets folder.Then i have used Xcode v11.2.1 functionality **"Convert to Scenekit File Format"** and able to covert the file into .scn file format. Next i have verified both USDZ, SCN file in Xcode and both file are showing properly.

**USDZ File**

[image]

**SCN File**

[image]

Now the problem is, when i have loaded the SCN file inside my ARKit based application, it is showing as black and i am not able to see any texture of the model.

[image]

I am aware of AR Quicklook framework but i don't want it. So any one has any experience how to fix above issue.

Comment: It looks like you should add some light source to the scene.

Comment: You could also set `sceneView.autoenablesDefaultLighting = true`

Answer (score 0):

sceneView.autoenablesDefaultLighting = true fixes the issue